# ThreadLocal-like in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: multithreading, smalltalk, pharo, thread-local

Is there an equivalent in Pharo for [ThreadLocals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) of Java, or a way to achieve similar behavior? For example, in Hibernate ThreadLocals are used to provide a thread (current request/context) "scoped" unity of work instance — named Session on Hibernate — through a single getCurrentSession method call. The developer don't need to worry and just believe that the method will return the right unit of work. Is that possible on Pharo?

I skimmed for this on Pharo Books (Pharo by example, Pharo enterprise and Deep Pharo) and [in this page](http://pillarhub.pharocloud.com/hub/Uko/concurrentProgrammingInPharo), but couldn't find useful information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in Pharo, you use a subclass of `ProcessLocalVariable`.
For example:

```
"Create a class to store you variable"
ProcessLocalVariable subclass: #MyVariable.

"Use it like this"
MyVariable value: myValue.

"Inside your code, access to current value like this"
MyVariable value.
```

Notice that even more powerful than thread local variables you have "dynamic variables" which are relative to the execution stack (more precise than threads) 
You use it like this:

```
"Create a class to store you variable"
DynamicVariable subclass: #MyVariable.

"Use it like this"
MyVariable 
    value: myValue 
    during: [ 
        "... execute your code here... usually a message send"
        self doMyCode ].

"Inside your code, access to current value like this"
MyVariable value.
```

This kind of variables offers same functionality (they are even more powerful) and are usually best replacement.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related curiosity: it is strictly necessary to create a subclass or I could use ProcessLocalVariable/DynamicVariable directly?

Comment: The only example I can think of where you might need a variable local to a process (or to a section of it) is a cache: you don't want the cache to be visible outside a specific computation. Do you know of any other cases where this could be useful?

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia, the Hibernate usage is one. You have a resource that caches during a specific process execution (entity state and queries result) and that provides functionality for users (list, update, delete etc). The alternatives are always clumsy, such as passing the same object everywhere. I don't think there aren't much applications though: it is occasionally useful I think.

Comment: @VitorCruz, if you do not subclass you will have just one variable available in the whole system, since they are accessible doing "MyVariable value". So I would say yes, you need one subclass for each variable (of course, one variable can be a complex object too, with many attributes).

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize it was a class side variable... Thanks!